# TeX sometimes displays incorrectly on search pages

Tags: bug, mathjax

When I type a search into the search box, sometimes the list of questions returned contains incorrectly handled TeX (of the sort that once was common all over the place here).

Here is an example: http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~rezk/mo-bug-exam.png.  The third question in the list is especially bad, but note that "\lambda" and "\Lambda" are not being converted in some of the other questions. The actual questions are correctly displayed on their own page.

Comment: I suppose your search terms (in particular, all instances of lambda) are highlighted in the result of the search, which interferes with their rendering by Mathjax.

Comment: And the reason for the rest of the mess is that the partial snippets of text taken from the original posts happen to have unbalanced dollar signs. In short, the search facility is apparently unaware that `$` has a special meaning.

Comment: @Emil: I suspect the second comment is the truer reason.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: What do you mean by truer? There are two issues with two reasons. Both are obvious from the HTML source.

Comment: This is a [known bug](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/8863/) which apparently is not easy to fix.